# Asyncfileupload file preview doesn't show and gives error Cannot set the property src of null

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asyncfileupload file preview doesn't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977393/asyncfileupload-file-preview-doesnt-show)

Hi 
Can some one clarify what is thiw error ., i got this error when i tried to change the image after the async file upload 
Here is my code:

```
function UploadComplete(sender, args) {
    var filename = args.get_fileName();
    var contentType = args.get_contentType();
    if (contentType.indexOf('image') == -1) {
        document.getElementById('<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').innerText = "Uploaded file must be an Image!"+ "<span style='color:red;'>" + args.get_errorMessage() + "</span>";
        document.getElementById('<%=AsyncFileUpload1.ClientID%>').text.style.backgroundColor = "Red";
    }
    else {
        var text = "" + filename + "      |      " + args.get_length() + " bytes"+"Uploaded Succesfully";
        document.getElementById('<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').innerText = text;
          $get("imageView1").src = "~/" + filename;
    }
}

<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="400px" runat="server"    
    OnClientUploadError="uploadError"    
    OnClientUploadStarted="StartUpload"  
    OnClientUploadComplete="UploadComplete"  
    CompleteBackColor="Lime" UploaderStyle="Modern"    
    ErrorBackColor="Red" ClientIDMode="AutoID"    
    ThrobberID="Throbber"    
    UploadingBackColor="#66CCFF" 
        onuploadedcomplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" /> 

<asp:Label ID="Throbber" runat="server" Style="display: none">
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgPreview" ImageUrl="~/Images/uploading.gif" />
    </asp:Label>
    <img runat="server" id="imageView1"/>
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Style="font-family: Arial; font-size: small;"></asp:Label>
```

Thanks in advance